# Remove app from alt-tab switcher

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I want an application removed from the alt-tab switcher.

I have tried CompizConfig Manager functions 'Skip taskbar' and 'Skip pager'.

First I tried setting 'window class', then tried 'window id', but neither of these  excluded the given application from switcher.

Are there any solutions to the matter?

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but CompizConfig Manager will most certainly won't work with 18.04 as this Ubuntu version uses GNOME instead of Unity+Compiz.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by setting the skip_taskbar hint on the window directly. For example, with wmctrl:

```
wmctrl -r "Window title" -b add,skip_taskbar
```

The window will be hidden from the window switcher, the dock, and the overview. You can get back to the window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> ("Switch system controls" in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu).

Curiously, Mutter also tracks the skip_pager hint, but never uses it.

#### Sources:

- Original Metacity bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106249
- Relevant commit in Mutter: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/d5a484479f43026f50a23f6453208dff158455bd

Comment: I confirm this works in Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: but it's a temporary solution, have to run it every time after app launch. How it can be done pernamently?

Comment: And sometimes it dosen't work.

Comment: It also works on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 20.2 (X-Cinnamon). Thanks!